# rendered not working in vf email template

Tags: singleemailmessage, vf-email-template

I am trying to dynamic render vf component inside a vf template using rendered attribute. But i am not getting any values and i am receiving a blank email.

Here i am trying to send email with attachment on ProductCode basis. If WorkOrderLineItem.Product2.ProductCode is "A" then send `c:test1`, If "B" then send `c:test2`

Does `rendered` work like this ?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test Subject" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="WorkOrderLineItem">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody > 
   {!relatedTo.Id}
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>

   <messaging:attachment renderAs="pdf" rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.Product2.ProductCode == 'A',true,false)}">
         <c:test1 wId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
    </messaging:attachment>
    
    <messaging:attachment renderAs="pdf" rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.Product2.ProductCode == 'B,true,false)}">
         <c:test2 wId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
    </messaging:attachment>
 
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you don't need your `IF` at all there. `relatedTo.Product2.ProductCode == 'A'` already evaluates to either `true` or `false`, so the `IF` function just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: try some simple debugging and display the value of {!relatedTo.Product2.ProductCode} in the email template directly. Does it have a value of A or B? if not you may have to tweak it.

Comment: try `relatedTo.PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductCode`.  On `xxxItem` standard objects, the `Product2` relationship is sometimes not available at runtime, depending on context but the `PricebookEntry.Product2` relationship is always present.